# Batch languge taskkill command

Tags: batch-file

Hi can someone remind me what was taskkil command in batch language? I just want to stop, for example notepad.
I tried /taskkill notepad.exe but it didnt worked

Comment: Bookmark [SS64.com on CMD](https://ss64.com/nt/) and then take a look at [their entry on `TASKKILL`](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html).

Comment: Where did you find this syntax on the web? ```/taskkill notepad.exe```  All you needed to do was open up a command prompt and type: `taskkill /?` to see the proper syntax usage.

Answer (score 1):

`Taskkill` is a very useful command, you can use it to end various processes as long you have permission, for instance:

> Ends one or more tasks or processes. Processes can be ended by
> process ID or image name. You can use the
> [tasklist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist)
> command command to determine the process ID (PID) for the process to
> be ended.
>
> ### Parameters:
>
> /F: Specifies that processes be forcefully ended.
>
> /IM `<imagename>`: Specifies the image name of the process to be
> terminated.
>
> /PID `<processID>`: Specifies the process ID of the process to be
> terminated. [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill)

You can end `notepad` using:

```
taskkill /IM "notepad.exe" /F
```

That command does:

- End the process called `notepad.exe`.
- Forcefully end it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command instead:

```
taskkill /f /im notepad.exe
```

or in script (*.bat)

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im notepad.exe
pause
```